# Why material-ui 'color' property of TextField works, but 'borderColor' doesn't?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I want to display an orange colored TextField, so I am trying:

```
<TextField
    id={field_meta.name}
    label={field_meta.title}
    defaultValue={field_meta.value? field_meta.value: ""}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    margin="normal"
    inputProps={{style: {borderColor: "orange"}}}
    fullWidth
    helperText={"Los cambios aún no se han guardado."}
/>
```

But the TextFields displays with regular colors:

[image]

What is curious, is that property 'color' does work;

```
<TextField
    id={field_meta.name}
    label={field_meta.title}
    defaultValue={field_meta.value? field_meta.value: ""}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    margin="normal"
    inputProps={{style: {color: "orange"}}}
    fullWidth
    helperText={"Los cambios aún no se han guardado."}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `TextField` has a border **set to 0**, so you need to give it a `borderWidth` and `borderStyle` property:

```
<TextField
    id={field_meta.name}
    label={field_meta.title}
    defaultValue={field_meta.value? field_meta.value: ""}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    margin="normal"
    inputProps={{style: {borderWidth: "2px", borderStyle: "solid", borderColor: "orange", color: "orange"}}}
    fullWidth
    helperText={"Los cambios aún no se han guardado."}
/>
```

Or, all in one go:

```
inputProps={{style: {border: "1px solid orange", color: "orange"}}}
```